# angular-highcharts conflicts with legacy application's highcharts lib

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Angular 2+ is used for new part of Spring MVC application where Highcharts is used. Later, highcharts charting (angular-highcharts) is added to new components written in angular 2+ technology. The same Highcharts 6 version is used at both sides.
At the time angular charting component is initialized Highcharts is already loaded in web page and following `Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16` is thrown.

Highcharts is not reloaded by angular component and `H.error(code, true)` is executed.
What is the best way to resolve this conflict?
Should additional `Highcharts_X` global variable for legacy web application be created? I don't prefer this approach because it is productively  used by Higcharts and then it should be changed in the source code at many places.(?)

Is it possible to tell angular-higcharts that the library is already loaded and to use that one?
Or to let it be reloaded without breaking JS with the error?

Comment: It looks like the problem with bundling your application. I don't see your whole code and it's hard to deduce how to resolve the problem, so I can only guess.

Comment: I agree with you. 
At the moment I'm at `Highcharts_X` hack with hope that better solution will be found in the future.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you resolved this conflict? I am facing same issue.

Comment: At the moment I'm not happy with solution. I'm using hacked Highcharts src in MVC where Highcharts gobal variable is renamed. So, angular plugin can initialize his own Highcharts.

Unfortunately I couldn't try https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/52#issuecomment-408055564 solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Global defined Highcharts instead of load Highcharts twice. 
For example:

```
//import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
declare var Highcharts: any;
```

You must remove loading module string and declare any Variable for build with no problems.

Comment: In that project Highcharts is used via angular2-highcharts dependency. So it would be needed to tell somehow to angular2-highcharts to use existing global Highcharts.

Comment: Yes, for angular2-highcharts you need declare var, like in my comment. It works in my angular 6  project and global loaded highcharts.